# Issue trying to extend control binding and setting custom xsltfinisher with docx4j

Tags: java, xslt, docx4j

I am trying to use docx4j to generate a report.  I have managed to create a word template and created and xml binding based on my data.

I can generate a docx output based on this using docx4j but now I need to do some conditional styling - based on a value shade a cell a certain color.

I have looked and tried to implement the [ContentControlBindingExtensions sample](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlBindingExtensions.java).

But I keep getting an error saying XsltCustomFinisher could not be found in Class Loader.

My code:

```java
private static void bindXMLToTemplateFinisher(WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage, String xml) throws Docx4JException, SAXException, IOException {

    XPathFactoryUtil.setxPathFactory(new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl());

    Document xmlDoc = convertStringToXMLDocument(xml);
    //ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    //String url = classloader.getResource("XsltFinishers/XsltFinisherCustom.xslt").getPath();

    Docx4jProperties.setProperty("docx4j.model.datastorage.XsltFinisher.xslt", "XsltFinisherReport.xslt");

    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlDoc, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML, null, new XsltProviderImpl(), "XsltFinisherReport.xslt", null);

}
```

I would expect to be able to set an xsltfinisher file but it does not seem to be able to find the one I am trying to use.

Any help to understand how to set and use a custom xslt finisher in docx4j would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To start with the basics, put XsltFinisherReport.xslt on your classpath as it says? In your IDE, this could mean adding the dir containing it to your classpath.

You can turn on logging for org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils for more diagnostics.

Per the documentation in XsltFinisher:

```
 * As an optional step after binding, apply user-defined XSLT to transform
 * this content control.
 * 
 * A template is attached to a content control (a repeat/condition/or normal bind),
 * using tag od:call=XYZ where XYZ is the template to call.
 * 
 * For example, by placing this on a repeat, a table tow could be coloured red if
 * its contents met some condition.
```

For example xslt, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/docx4j-samples-resources/src/main/resources